# Oracle SQL: Case in Select overwrites values instead of adding them

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, partition

I am new to Oracle and maybe use the wrong approach here.

**Current result:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

[image]

The **problem is that in my case the text "Items" appears instead of the first item** for each ID instead of above it.

**My query (simplified):**

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.ID ORDER BY sd.ITEM) = 1 THEN sd.ID
        ELSE '' 
    END AS ID
    , CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.ID ORDER BY sd.ITEM) = 1 THEN 'Items'
        ELSE sd.ITEM
    END AS Details
    , CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.ID ORDER BY sd.ITEM) = 1 THEN TO_CHAR((sd.SUBTOTAL + sd.SUBTOTAL_TAX), 'FM9,990.00')
        ELSE '' 
    END AS Total_Price
FROM
    SHIP_DETAILS sd
/* ... */
```

**Note:**  Total price in the screenshots above is just a placeholder to explain the content, it would just be a sum amount.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Many thanks in advance for any help,
Mike

Comment: Remove the single quotes.  You have defined a string, not a column reference.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, Gordon. I want the actual string for the first row of each ID and the column values only for the other rows. I added screenshots to explain what I mean. Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

The `case` statement does not generate *new* rows.  So, you have a choice between `'item'` or the first item.

I suspect that you want to use `grouping sets` (or `with rollup`).  Here is an [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) that explains these `group by` modifiers.

Comment: Thanks again, Gordon ! I get your point. I think ROLLUP is what I need here as I am trying to show the subtotals not next to the first item for each ID but instead on a separate row. Will look into the article.